# .Net Windows application code review check list

Tags: .net

I need to prepare check list for .Net windows application. It should include security, Design and coding standards. I googled but no luck. am getting for asp.Net not for Windows appliation. Is there any check list available for this ?

Thanks in advance..

Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For coding standards, one can refer to [Microsoft coding standards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx).

To enforce such coding standards, one can use FxCop or Stylecop. Generally checklists are prepared in the organization perspective and are IPR for that organization. So naturally it won't be easily avaliable freely.IEEE also has some good guidelines on this subject but those also doesn't come free.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna check out the following link:

[Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)